# Django Class-based mixin view does not return a HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Trying to use a mixin to create a class-based view in Django but keep getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: The view twitter.views.TwitterExampleView didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

As shown in the code below, I extend from View creating a base TwitterView for the app to handle error messages being returned from Twitter. That view is further extended for a TwitterNetworkView where a Twitter network is attached to the view. The other classes allow for some transformation to happen to parameters passed into requests. The final class, the TwitterExampleView, includes both the mixin for parameter transformation and the TwitterNetworkView. It's get method returns as a placeholder a string "blah". Only when it bubbles back into the dispatch is the response rendered so what am I overlooking?

```
class TwitterView(View):

  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        response = super(TwitterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return render_response(request, response)
    except TwitterApiException, e:
        return return_error(request, e, e.status_code)

class TwitterNetworkView(TwitterView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.network = get_network_or_404(request.user, kwargs['network_id'])
        super(TwitterNetworkView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class DefineParamsMixin(object):
  def get_params(self):
    return null

class TwitterPagedDefineParams(DefineParamsMixin):
  def get_params(self):
    return define_params(
            Param('page'),
            Param('since'),
            Param('before'),
            Param('limit', transform_func=int)
        )

class TwitterExampleView(TwitterPagedDefineParams, TwitterNetworkView):

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return "blahhhhh"
```

Comment: well, not sure if I understand your question. However, the error message makes sense. since you returned 'blahhhh' in your .get() methods. I mean, regardless how you build your view, django expects HttpResponse object.

Comment: What do your `render_response` and `return_error` calls return? Unless I'm missing something in the inheritance chain, those are what will prepare the final return value. Getting `response="blahhhhh"` in your `TwitterExampleView` case.

Comment: the render_response --> return HttpResponse(data, content_type=content_type, status=status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `dispatch` in your `TwitterNetworkView` mixin. With no `return` statement, the method returns `None` rather than an `HttpResponse`. One fix would be to have it return the result of `super(TwitterNetworkView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: You have the eyes of a falcon - I have been moving things around and clearly overlooked that. Thank you for saving me from .. well myself! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) object.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

...

class TwitterExampleView(TwitterPagedDefineParams, TwitterNetworkView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("blahhhhh")
```

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view

Comment: my render_response method returns a HttpResponse --> return HttpResponse(data, content_type=content_type, status=status)